# PHP Login - if(empty)$password doesn't work in my code, why?

Tags: php, encryption, authentication, md5

So I was playing around with my simple login system, and one thing I can't seem to figure out is why the login allows me to create an account with only an username and send this data to my database event though I specified

```
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
```

and

```
    if(empty($username)) {
      echo("Du ma fylle inn et brukernavn!");
} {
 if(empty($password)) {
      echo("Du ma fylle inn et passord!");
      } else {
```

When I remove (md5 in the escape string, it works, but then there is no encryption and the password is visible in the database. So it's kind of vice versa.. anyone see where my mistake or missunderstanding is?

**QUICK SUM: It's supposed to give "You need to fill in password" but it doesn't when I have the md5 decrypting in the string, however when I remove it, it allows me.**

Comment: Don't hash the password with MD5. Use Bcrypt or pbkdf2. MD5 is not enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the field is empty before you assign md5-

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    if (mysql_real_escape_string(empty($_POST['password']))) {
        // do nothing
    } 
    else 
    {
   `    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));

        if(empty($username)) {
             echo("Du ma fylle inn et brukernavn!");
        } {
        if(empty($password)) {
             echo("Du ma fylle inn et passord!");
        } else {
        }
   }
```

}

Comment: Thanks a lot to all of you! Got it fixed, especially thanks to Kev and Femaref for more in-depth.

Comment: I take it back, still can't fix it actually. I'm failing to place an ending somewhere.. 
?>

Answer (score 2):

`md5` will result in a string, even though the input is empty. You need to check the original input, straight from `$_POST`. If you want to validate input, always check before processing it, as subsequent processing (as you have seen in this case) can result in non-empty variables, even though the original input was empty.

Answer (score 2):

md5 will encode ANYTHING, even an empty string. Which will make the variable 'non-empty', no matter what.

Meaning: Do your check on empty first, THEN encode your password.

Answer (score 1):

An empty string still has an MD5 hash, so you're getting a correct check that the password equals something.